# Taking an index of object in Array with swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am new at objective c, so i am sorry if my question is easy. I have array of images

```
 NSMutableArray *arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:_boxImage,_emptyImage,_emptyRightImage,_emptyDownImage,_emptyCornerRightImage,_emptyCornerLeftImage];
```

and i have got swipe gesture, i need to get index of object in array, that is chosen to move in some way. I tried to use

```
[arrayOfImages indexOfObject:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
```

but it doesnt work.

can you give me some advices about this?

thank you for your time

Comment: How do you display these images ? using `UIScrollView` with `UIPageControl` ? `UIPageControl` increases/decreases page number to one in swipe direction ? Have you checked that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOfObject` receives an integer, specifying index of exact object you want to get, and `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` won't have the value same as your desired object's index !

You should get the position where the gesture is initiated and check to see which image is placed at that area ! A totally different approach !